# App contains default.realm file yet "No default RealmConfiguration was found. Call setDefaultConfiguration() first"

Tags: android, realm, jdbcrealm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I am Converting CSV file to realm file on **APP ONE** then shipping this as the primary database in the **APP TWO** and setting as default database using

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
    if (isFirstRun)
    {



        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .migration(new in.webic.oralcalculations.Row())
                .assetFile(context, "Default.realm")
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .build();

        realm = realm.getInstance(config);
        realm.close();


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
        editor.commit();

    }
```

and default.realm is saved in the app directory
[image]

in my another activity i am trying to use this db by

```
 public void prepare_test(int id){
    realm = realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<RowNew> result2 = realm.where(RowNew.class)
            .equalTo("course", id)
            .findAll();
    String a="";
    for (RowNew u : result2) {
        a+=" "+u.getQp1();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,a,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

giving me error

> No default RealmConfiguration was found. Call setDefaultConfiguration() first

yet i have already shown the creation of the default db in the app
any help will be appritiated
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [initialize your realm default config](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#the-default-realmconfiguration) as you doing this in first application. It's required even if you mannually transfer database file